# Editing Chrome omnibox history

Tags: google-chrome, history, address-bar

I was wondering if it is possible to modify what values show up in the Chrome omnibox when typing certain phrases.

For example, when I start typing "basecamp" it goes to basecamp.com/#####/projects/#####-old-project-im-not-on. I'd like it to either not have this one show up at all or instead prefer basecamp.com/#####/projects/#####-brand-spakin-new-project-yay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend, who is crazy and doesn't want delicious SE points, told me the solution.

1. Start typing what you'd like to remove
2. Highlight the item using the keyboard
3. Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and press <kbd>delete</kbd>. (On a Mac laptop, <kbd>backspace</kbd> is labeled as <kbd>delete</kbd>, so you'll also have to also hold <kbd>fn</kbd> when hitting <kbd>delete</kbd>)

As a side note, I've noticed that this won't work in all cases. My hypothesis is that this happens when there aren't enough matches or a page is unique for your entry.

Comment: This also doesn't work on newer versions of Chrome (I'm on 41). There's this thread where others are confirming this tip not working too: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6VJdCx_Y2Mg